# Does Flex 3 support localization/Globalization feature?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flex3

I tried to develop my application to support Localization. Currently i am using flex 3.
Will Flex 3 have localization libraries to support

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There are a couple of links to articles I have gathered on using the ResourceManager class for internationalization, and the properties files for localization.

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flex/flex_internationalization.htm

**EDITED:**

Short summary:  ResourceManager (and the IResourceManager interface) allow you to specify "resource bundles" (the localization information), and get resources (like strings or numbers) based on the specified locale.  Then, a property file for the resources of a specific language are created.

String resources also allow for ordered parameter insertion, where different language requirements may require different order of parameters (i.e., "Insert {0} into file {1}" vs. "Into file {1} insert {0}")

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But these are in Flex 4 i believe. I wanted to know if these features are there in Flex 3

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'll edit my answer to include a brief summary of what's required.  And from what I can tell (although I'm using Flex 4), the ResourceManager class is part of Flex 3 (checking the Flex documentation).